# Samba server that allows all Linux characters in file names

Tags: linux, samba

I don't use any Windows client and would like to have a Samba server that allows all characters in file names that Linux supports. Is this possible?
Examples: Foo"Bar or Bar:Baz

Comment: If you don't have Windows clients, why do you want Samba?

Comment: For me setting up the shares and user management with samba far easier than with NFS.

Answer (score 0):

Set `mangled names = no` in your `smb.conf`.

Bear in mind that some clients may hide files with names they don't support so you may need to use the `catia` VFS object to remap characters if you find that being a problem.